# How to change the column the code is calling for in Google Sheet App script?

Tags: google-apps-script, drop-down-menu, google-sheets

I'm using a app script code from: https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-apps-script-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-data-validation-lists/

to use dependent drop down data validation lists on a google sheet document.

The code is working but now I need to make it work on our office google sheet document. The code is made to work from the first column, but I need it to work on the E column of our document.

I've tried changing  : 
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() >1){

to : if(activeCell.getColumn() == 5 && activeCell.getRow() >1){

but it doesn't work, the code was working only on first column
and now it doesn't work at all, since I've been trying some things, even if it seems to me that I didn't change anything really beside the number of the column...

Here's my test google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_bc6FsxiE8a0J8XElv6SyjnXXtwc0qjoJ_MuSkHcUg/edit#gid=1591147038

And here's the code :

```
function onEdit(){

 var tablists = "Listes"
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tabLists");

 var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();


  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 5 && activeCell.getRow() >1){ 

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var projets = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var projetsIndex = projets[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue())+1;

    if(projetsIndex ! = 0) {

      var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, projetsIndex, datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```

If you have any idea on what I'm missing ! 
Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found out ! 
It was missing a semicolon on the second row of the code : 
var tablists = "Listes"

Now it works !